# How to set pip for python in windows 8

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am a beginner to python programming, i have downloaded the python 3.6.1 version and installed it i  have also trying to run with the idle file and the command prompt is coming . i have also set the path to environment variables in windows, but the problem is that when i am typing the command

```
 pip install sklearn
```

the error showing is "syntaxError: invalid syntax" .It is not also recognizing the pip command also like it is giving

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
  pip
NameError: name 'pip' is not defined
```

how i can use it please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install pip separately first, meaning that the python install didn't include it for some reason.

This should have you covered: [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Download get-pip.py from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py. As a .py file!

Then via command prompt you can do the following:
python get-pip.py

This solved it for myself.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to execute a Linux code in a Python console. If you are using Win8, I would recommend to download and execute the [Windows version of sklearn](https://winpython.github.io/).